# Similar Function to MenuItemDisplayStr() as non-intrinsic? (AX 2012)

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I am writing a class that needs to validate a string as an existing menuItem.  Ideally, I would need something similar to MenuItemDisplayStr(), but I need it to use that function at runtime as opposed to compile time.  Is there something similar that can check a string if it is a menuItem?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You will have to iterate the AOT and compare the string to the menu items.

This code is adapted from the example provided here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsiebold/2010/08/13/use-x-to-loop-through-the-aot/

```
#AOT

//These are the macros for the paths found in #AOT. 
//Don't use macros in practice. It's a bad habit.
//#define.MenuItemsDisplayPath('\\Menu Items\\Display')
//#define.MenuItemsOutputPath('\\Menu Items\\Output')
//#define.MenuItemsActionPath('\\Menu Items\\Action')

TreeNode menuItemParentNode;

//str menuItemName = "derp";//output: "derp is not a valid menu item"
str menuItemName = "ActivitiesMain";//output: "ActivitiesMain is a valid menu item"

//Only checking display here, you would need another level of 
//nodes to do output and actions.
menuItemParentNode = TreeNode::findNode(#MenuItemsDisplayPath);

if (menuItemParentNode.AOTfindChild(menuItemName))
    info(strFmt("%1 is a valid menu item", menuItemName));
else
    info(strFmt("%1 is not a valid menu item", menuItemName));
```